# Why is there no Dispose function in Thread class

Tags: c#, multithreading, winapi

In the Win32 API world, there is `CreateThread()` to create a thread and `CloseHandle()` to close the thread handle. But in the .NET framework, the `System.Threading.Thread` class has no `Dispose()` or `Close()` methods. I wonder, in the case of .NET, when will the OS thread be closed? During Garbage Collection?

Comment: Thread is automatically disposed when its done with its work.

Comment: You can call `Join` to wait for the thread to complete

Comment: `CloseHandle()` does not destroy, terminate or suspend the thread, it only destroys the handle itself. The thread continues to work normally. In .NET, the `Thread` class derives from `CriticalFinalizerObject`, so the internal handle will be closed by the finalizer.

Comment: @dymanoid So handle will not be destroyed till GC?

Comment: Why do you care about the thread's handle at all?

Comment: @dynamoid This is a question from my code reviewer about not closing the thread object. So I am trying to understand the implementation.

Comment: *"when will the OS thread be closed"* - You seem to be positive that a CLR thread maps to an OS thread. Have you verified that assumption?

Answer (score 2):

An instance of the `Thread` class is just a managed object that represents a thread. The actual thread is owned and managed by the CLR.

Comment: When an `actual` thread that CLR manages gets disposed/created?

Comment: @cassandrad I'm not sure I follow. There's nothing special about these threads. They are just created and managed by the CLR. I.e. the CLR will call `CloseHandle` when the thread is no longer needed.

Comment: I understand that. Was interested in do you know how CLR decides that more threads are required or that some thread should be halted. It looks like it's not that easy to find that information from CLR source code.

Comment: @cassandrad these are obviously implementation details so don't rely on any of this. However, there are two different scenarios here. Threads created by the CLR to do it needs, e.g. the finalizer thread and threads your code creates. The former will run as long as needed by the CLR. The latter will run as long as the code you assign to the thread runs (or the thread gets terminated for some reason). After that the thread is cleaned up and the `Thread` object can be reclaimed. You'll sometimes see that the instances of `Thread` is still around on the heap after the thread is done running.